# How to set up mac for graphics programming to use openGL?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, 3d

> I am a new to programming and also to this platform so i apologize if
>   my question is not proper or seems stupid but i need help .None of the
>   resources on internet have been useful to me . If possible please
>   provide step by step instrction to set up mac for graphics
>   programming. thank you in advance.

I am a new to programming and i am trying to learn graphics programming .Till now i write c/c++ code in a text editor and compile and execute them to see the output in shell . I searched the web for setting up mac for opengl projects but none of them come close to clearing my doubts . Here are the doubts/questions :

**my computer**: macOS-Mojave :macbook pro mid 2012 (intel hd graphics 4000) supports openGL 4.1 according to apple website

**1**. do i have to download some files to use openGL ? or is it just a an api implemented by the computer hardware manufacturer(here apple in my case ).

**2**. according to recent news apple deprecated openGL. And i don't know      which version of openGL is on my macbook . is there a way to find out  ?None of the answers listed have worked for me.

**3**.Can i compile openGL code through terminal like i have been doing till now or do i have to use xcode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. do i have to download some files to use openGL?

So far, not yet. Everything required ships with the compilers by default. You just add `-framework OpenGL` to your compiler invocations and are good to go.

> 2. according to recent news apple deprecated OpenGL. And i don't know which version of openGL is on my macbook. is there a way to find out? None of the answers listed have worked for me.

You're mixing two different concepts here:

- The deprecation of OpenGL in the macOS platform means, that OpenGL will disappear from that OS altogether, irrespective of what OpenGL version actually is supported. Eventually you'll have to either move to Metal, or use some wrapper like MoltenGL (which implements OpenGL on top of Metal) or [MoltenVK (which implements Vulkan on top of Metal)](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK).
- With macOS the highest OpenGL version supported is determined entirely by the version of macOS installed. That is different from other OS, where a mere driver update may give you a higher OpenGL version, as long as the installed graphics hardware meets the requirements of that higher OpenGL version.

> 3. Can i compile openGL code through terminal like i have been doing till now or do i have to use xcode?

Yes. And there's no difference between compiling from the command line, and through Xcode, because Xcode is just doing the very same command calls as you'd do through the terminal.

Comment: thank you @datenwolf for taking out the time to answer my question . can you advise me on how should i go along if i want to learn graphics programming then if openGL will be removed ? since metal only supports objective c and swift . Thankyou.

Comment: @MADARAMINOSHI: If you want to stay on macOS, for long term viability, you can either bite the bullet and use Metal *and thereby lock yourself into that one, and only that ecosystem under control of that single one vendor.* Or you can grab yourself MoltenVK, which is free and open source, and use that as a layer between a proprietary API and your code which you write against a cross platform, industry standard, namely Vulkan. Vulkan isn't the most friendly API to learn, but it looks a lot, like it will have the best support of all APIs in the years to come.

Comment: @MADARAMINOSHI: You can still learn OpenGL, but beware old tutorials which touch the fixed function pipeline. If you want to start learning OpenGL (which is not a bad thing), limit yourself entirely to the core profiles.

Comment: i have been practising c++ since last month having a goal to make a simple file sharing application using sockets . still reading on it . thought to learn graphics programming since i am an artist too and love the visual stuffs too so it seemed interesting. Avoiding metal as only for apple. thanks to your suggestion about vulkan . have started to search tutorials for setting it up . if you can give any more advice since you seem to be really experienced then i would be really glad .And thanks a lot for clearing my doubts .saved a lot of my time . Thank you.

Comment: @MADARAMINOSHI: If you want to get your feet wet with graphics programming, I can't nearly enough recommend ShaderToy: https://www.shadertoy.com/ – also if you're looking for a "stable" graphics programming environment, that's not going to be deprecated and is beginner friendly, have a look at WebGL. WebGL is derived from OpenGL-ES. And as far as shaders are concerned, there's only very little differences between OpenGL (desktop), OpenGL-ES (embedded, mobile) and WebGL. So what you learn on ShaderToy is applicable immediately to the related APIs.

Comment: thank you @datenwolf for the suggestions . though i am not sure of how to use shadertoy.com . it looks like instagram for experienced graphics programmers. And i think for applying webGL i need to learn javascript which makes the learning curve much steeper. Will surely try it if everything fails. thanks.

Comment: @MADARAMINOSHI: To use OpenGL you *must* learn GLSL (the OpenGL Shader Language). It's the same language as used by ShaderToy, and the concepts of uniforms, attributes and the other inputs and outputs are the same for desktop OpenGL. So must learn that anyway. The nice thing about GLSL is, that it applies to OpenGL *and* OpenGL-ES *and* WebGL *and* Vulkan.